# NOT IN with OR operator MYSQL

Tags: mysql, notin, or-operator

I want to select rows where in a row, **sender** is not equal to any of the list element and if it is not equal , then check if **recipient** is not equal to any of the list element .Using NOT IN () having OR operator like:

```
SELECT * FROM messages WHERE ((sender NOT IN ( 'user1','3' )) OR (recipient NOT IN ( 'user1','3' )))
```

**PROBLEM:**

> This is not filtering the data and giving the results just like before!

Although this indeed works:

```
SELECT * FROM messages WHERE (recipient NOT IN ( 'user1','3' ))
```

What should be changed?

Comment: The error message is straight forward. There is no column named `user1`. If you want to specify the string `'user1'` instead, then you must enclose it in single quotation marks. `array('user' => "'user1'")`.

Comment: Is the use of OR is correct?

Comment: I don't know, too many parenthesis, just fix the syntax, run it again and see what it does.

Comment: Can you provide an example my code is a bit complex and i just stuck right at this , Not getting the expected results

Comment: As I said, change your array to `array('user' => "'user1'")` and see if it works or what changes. When in doubt, dump the SQL query to see what you are actually requesting from the server, it makes it a lot easier to spot the problem.

Comment: Format your code properly.  No one is going to read long, one-liner code.

Comment: Ok i have tried the quotation and it does work but not working with OR .OR operator is not working and its just giving me the same results as before.

Comment: Is there a column named user1 in your database? Or is it named user? The contents of notinq are 'user1', which means the only column you are looking for is the column user1.

Comment: @bhooks Please check the update now.

Comment: I'm sure there's nothing wrong with the operator, perhaps it's your logic. `(sender NOT IN ( 'user1','3' )) OR (recipient NOT IN ( 'user1','3' ))` **is always true except** when `sender` and `recipient` are the same (user sending a message to himself).

Comment: @Havenard Yeah i know its nothing wrong with operator Can you please tell me how can i do what i want to achieve with logic?

Comment: Well a simple solution is to use `AND`. Is there any reason why it has to be done with `NOT IN` and `OR`?

Comment: Because i have an array of usernames that i convert into list using `implode` .As you said `AND` can be used ,please show me how to do it

Comment: @Thanks guyz i have added the answer

Answer (score 0):

For future readers, the above comments gave me an idea how to use OR with NOT IN as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM messages WHERE (sender OR recipient NOT IN ( 'user1','3' ))
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you need

```
where
   NOT (   sender IN ( 'user1','3' )
        OR recipient IN ( 'user1','3' )
       )
```

So here, the wrapped OR condition is... The sender IS one of the list OR the recipient IS one of the list.  The outer throws the NOT.

Comment: This looks good too but please can you confirm my answer above?

Comment: @MR_AMDEV, your answer I don't even think will query accurately.  Any non-zero value of "sender" will return true.  So your condition I BELIEVE is implied as...  where (sender) or (recipient not in ( 'user1', '3')) even though you don't explicitly have parens in your query.